# ValueError: shapes not aligned, but I don't understand the error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning

Hi I'm watching a youtube machine learning lecture and I'm copying the code that is written there.  I get an error message on this bit of code:

```
def forward_propagate(self, inputs):
    activations = inputs
    for weight in self.weights:
        #calculate net inputs
        net_inputs = np.dot(activations, weight)
```

"activations" is an array with dimensions (3,) as shown when I type in activations.shape in ipython

"weight" is an array with dimensions (3,3)

This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lesson6.py", line 51, in <module>
    outputs = mlp.forward_propagate(inputs)
  File "lesson6.py", line 29, in forward_propagate
    net_inputs = np.dot(activations, weight)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (3,) and (5,2) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 5 (dim 0)
```

What is being referred to in the (5,2)?  I put an import pdb pdb.set_trace() right before the error and the array shapes that are passed in are (3,) and (3,3)?

Comment: Can you please show a [mre]?

Comment: The error message suggests that the weights are actually (5,2) rather than (3,3) as you suggest. Could you provide more of your code in order to provide context?

Comment: @mandulaj you're right.  In trying to come up with a minimal reproducible example as shown through mkrieger1 link...I found that (3,3) dimension was true for the first iteration but on a subsequent iteration of "weight", the dimension was (5,2)....now to figure out how that got in there....